# get user with token django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

sorry for my english. It is not good.

I work with rest framework django. I want to recover a user with his token. This Token must be sent via a post request

```
class GetUser(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
serializer_class = serializers.UserBasicSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    return models.Member.objects.filter()

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = Token.objects.get(*args, **kwargs).user
```

i receive this error message

```
rest_framework.authtoken.models.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Token -- it returned 2!
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use:
`user = Token.objects.filter(*args, **kwargs)`

`if user.exists():
    user = user.last().user`

Comment: While this code-only answer may answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so. This will help future users evaluate the answer for their situation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is in the docs. Take a look here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#user

Basically, you just need to get from request the method user. For example:

```
def api_name_of_api(request):
   user_data = request.user  # Get username
   user_data = request.user.id  # Get user id
   ...
```